# workbox with vue js

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, workbox-webpack-plugin

I want to use fallback page with vue component but not getting in response. So currently returning html page if no response. but i need to return Vue Component. I am using networkFirst strategy.

```
const offlineUrl = 'static/offline.html';

let networkFirstHandler = workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
  cacheName: 'default',
  plugins: [
    new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
      maxEntries: 50
    }),
    new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
      statuses: [200]
    })
  ]
});

const matcher = ({event}) => event.request.mode === 'navigate';

const handler = (args) => networkFirstHandler.handle(args).then((response) => (!response) ? caches.match(offlineUrl) : response);
```

But here in OfflineUrl I want to return my Vue Component.